# What's the standard way to store html text, and make it searchable in a database?

Tags: html, database

I'm working on an Evernote like notetaking application. When I type up HTML formatted notes (currently adding HTML tags by hand), I store the whole HTML body in a VARCHAR field in my database.
I then extra only the plain text portion from that HTML body, and store that in a different VARCHAR field for which I've enabled FullText searching capabilities on.

This gives me the power of better search results (I've not getting records presented when I search '<h1>' lol), and rich HTML view of the text.

So my question is:

###### Is this the standard or best way of doing it?

The biggest downside I see to this is 'wasted' (dunno if you'd call it that) storage space. For each note record added, I'm store it twice (HTML & plaintext).

I've realizing as I'm typing this that indeed StackOverflow has had to manage this somehow. As I'm typing on typing HTML tags on top, it's presenting me with formatting view below (which I'm sure they only index that portion).

Any guidance or suggestions greatly appreciated,

Thanks!